# Vb.net to mySQL datetime conversion

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Hi i have this code and it give me error:

> Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <10/1/2012
>   3:43:30 PM> in time_in_am Column.  Expected type is MySqlDateTime.

my mySQL data type for "time_in_am" is DateTime.

```
dataRow = dataSet.Tables(0).NewRow()
dataRow("time_in_am") = DateTime.Now
dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dataRow)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe MySQL's accepted DateTime format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

So, alter the 2nd row of your code to:

```
dataRow("time_in_am") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

For what each of the format 'magic strings' mean, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#Y200)

If you find yourself using this often (which is probable) you can create an extension:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module MyExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToMySql(d As Date) As String
        Return d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    End Function

End Module
```

Now you can use this in your code as follows:

```
dataRow("time_in_am") = DateTime.Now.ToMySql()
```

Comment: this gives me: 'Format' is not a member of 'Date'.

Comment: i got it...just replace d.Format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") with d.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") and everythings go smooth...cheers

Comment: sorry, should have copied and pasted rather than retyping. edited the answer to correct it

Answer (score 0):

```
Return d.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

will solve it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think another shortest way to do it is using Format()

`dataRow("time_in_am") = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score -1):

i was looking a way to convert this vb6 date conversion to mysql accepted value to vb.net;

'convert date to mysql format

```
Public Function convToYMD(strDate)

strYear = CStr(Year(strDate))
strmonth = CStr(Month(strDate))
strday = CStr(Day(strDate))
strhour = CStr(Hour(strDate))
strminute = CStr(Minute(strDate))
strsecond = CStr(Second(strDate))

If Len(strhour) = 1 Then
    strhour = "0" & strhour
ElseIf Len(strhour) = 0 Then
    strhour = "00"
End If

If Len(strminute) = 1 Then
    strminute = "0" & strminute
ElseIf Len(strminute) = 0 Then
    strminute = "00"
End If

If Len(strsecond) = 1 Then
    strsecond = "0" & strsecond
ElseIf Len(strsecond) = 0 Then
    strsecond = "00"
End If

If Len(strday) = 1 Then
    strday = "0" + strday
ElseIf Len(strday) = 0 Then
    strday = "00"
End If

If Len(strmonth) = 1 Then
    strmonth = "0" & strmonth
ElseIf Len(strmonth) = 0 Then
    strmonth = "00"
End If

convToYMD = strYear + "-" + strmonth + "-" + strday + " " + strhour + ":" + strminute + ":" + strsecond

end function
```

found this code and solves my problem! 
i just added inside the module

```
 If DateFormat.ShortDate Then
         Return d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    ElseIf DateFormat.LongDate Then
         Return d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    End If
```

many, many thanks!